# A function to load a simple plugin acts different when called during start-up

Tags: vim

I have simple pseudo vim plugin that I use to test and observe how things are executed by VIM. So here is my function that I use to trigger the plugin:

```
function! myCore#load_plugin()
    let s:plugin_core = '/broadcast/foo/dev/myVimBundles'
    echo "---> " . s:plugin_core . " <---"
    NeoBundle 'myDummyPlugin', {'name' : 'myDummyPlugin', 'base' : '/broadcast/foo/dev/myVimBundles', 'directory' : 'myDummyPlugin'}
endfunction
```

So when I call this function as part of a start up script, like for example inside my .vimrc, I can see that the plugin files inside "/myDummyPlugin/plugin" and "/myDummyPlugin/after/plugin" are loaded but the "syntax", "indent" and "ftdetect" are ignored.

However once VIM is started and I call the very same function above, it executes perfectly including all the file type, index and syntax components.

I find this really strange, any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you open an issue with NeoBundle? Its author should be in the best position to help you.

Comment: Hi, sure. I will do that. But I have the feeling that I might be doing something wrong. All plugin loading frameworks (ex: VAM, pathogen etc.) have a similar syntax when it comes to loading bespoke plugins. So I thought that maybe I am doing something wrong from the VIM point of view. But yeah, I will probably start an issue. Thanks.

Comment: Are `filetype plugin indent on` and `syntax on` *below* or *above* your function call in your vimrc?

Comment: This is how it is: first "filetype plugin indent on" then "syntax on" and finally "call myCore#Load_myDummyPlugin()" I have tired different combinations with no luck. Thanks.

Comment: I have started an issue and explained the problem in detail here: https://github.com/Shougo/neobundle.vim/issues/176 Could you please help me? Thanks!

Comment: The answer is: FIRST: "call Load_myDummyPlugin()" THEN: "filetype plugin indent on" LAST: "NeoBundleCheck". So the order matters.